# Unable to create NSURL with special characters (éè) with Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl

I am unable to load an image because of nil returned by NSURL. The url looks like this : http://www.example.fr/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/préliminaire.jpg. When I enter my URL on firefox, I get my image but when I try in firefox the encoder http://www.example.fr/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/pr%3Flinaire.jpg I have no image...

Here is the code I use to load my image :

```
NSString *myString = @"http://www.example.fr/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/préliminaire.jpg";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:myString];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];
```

That returns nil for url, so everything after is nil..

Thank you for your help guys

Answer (score 7):

That's because those characters are not valid in a URL.  Escape them first:

```
NSString *escaped = [myString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:escaped];
// etc.
```